# Converting a pdf content in binary from database to a pdf file

Tags: c#, sql-server, pdf

I have a pdf content in database with a type of varbinary(MAX) starts with

> 0x255044462D312E350A25E2E3CFD30A312030206F626A0A3C3C2F547970652F584F626A6563742F537562747970652F496D6167652F5769647468203232362F486569676874203232362F4C656E6774682037312F436F6C6F.....

this is may code, but it does not work.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private byte[] StringToByteArray(string str)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return enc.GetBytes(str);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();

    comm.CommandText = "Select document_content FROM[Document] WHERE documant_id= @id_doc";
    comm.Connection = cn;
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_doc", 1241);

    using (SqlDataReader oReader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (oReader.Read())
        {
            downloadedDoc = oReader["document_content"].ToString();
        }
    }
    cn.Close();

    byte[] downloadedPDF = StringToByteArray(downloadedDoc);

    File.WriteAllBytes(@"mypath", downloadedPDF);

}
```

Comment: *"it does not work"*. You need to expand on this. What does "not work" mean? Help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is a bad idea to first serialize to string and that to byte array, if the output from your SQL query is already binary.

I would try to cast it directly:

```
byte[] downloadedPdf = (byte[])oReader["document_content"];
```